# Why do developers with access to the source code who are testing out my app need a provisioning profile?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms app.

My developer is asking for a provisioning profile to be able to test the app on his own iPhone but he already has full access to the repro with the source code.

Can someone explain why the provisioning profile is also needed?

Answer (score -1):

A provisioning profile is required by Apple in order to deploy an ad-hoc build to a physical device.

Comment: But for a developer with full access to all of the source code, would they not be able to create there own just like they would do if they were creating there own app?  Also would there be an option of just adding the device UDID to the current profile?

Comment: If they have a developer account they could create their own profile.  And yes, you can add their device to an existing profile.

Comment: I'm getting rather confused here.  Can you confirm that if I am learning about Xamarin for the first time, I run the sample app but then I cannot deploy it to my own phone without a developer account.  How about if I know the UDID of the phone?  Then I can just add that to the profile.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xamarin - it's purely Apple.  "Then I can just add that to the profile." - you need a developer account to create a provisioning profile.  See https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev5a825a1ca